# Wordnet::Similarity installation issue

Tags: macos, perl, command-line, installation, wordnet

When I install [`Wordnet::Similarity`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WordNet::Similarity) on mac, the following error occur:

```
usr/local/bin/perl "-Iblib/arch" "-Iblib/lib" build/Depthfiles.PL blib/lib/WordNet/synsetdepths.dat
Generating default depth files.
Can't load '/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/darwin-2level/auto/Digest/SHA1/SHA1.bundle' for module Digest::SHA1: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/darwin-2level/auto/Digest/SHA1/SHA1.bundle, 1): no suitable image found. Did find:
    /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/darwin-2level/auto/Digest/SHA1/SHA1.bundle: mach-o, but wrong architecture at /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.8.8/darwin-2level/DynaLoader.pm line 230.
 at blib/lib/WordNet/Tools.pm line 76
Compilation failed in require at blib/lib/WordNet/Tools.pm line 76.
```

My attempt was to enter to the downloaded package directory from terminal and type:

```
 perl Makefile.PL

 make

 make test

 sudo make install
```

I made sure to have installed all prerequisite http://search.cpan.org/dist/WordNet-Similarity/doc/install.pod#Prerequisites. I suspect that this may be due to mac processor version with Perl interface. Any suggestion on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Install libdigest-sha-perl in Ubuntu 14.04 has solved this issue.

Download link:http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/perl/libdigest-sha-perl